# verify user login credentials using gmail (or other email service provider)

Tags: asp.net

How to verify users login credentials using users login credentials of user's gmail account (like in stackoverflow on clicking gmail it takes to gmail login page and gmail verifies the user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably referring to [OpenID](http://openid.net/). GMail is just one provider of OpenIDs - there are plenty of others and you can create your own.